# My Simple String Implementation Gone Wrong

Tags: c++, string

I am creating my simple implementation of the String class like in the .Net framework. The only difference, it is less sugary if you know what I am mean. Anyhow, I got it everything to work except for the overloaded operators for the + operator; which end up displaying a garbage buffer. I still have not implemented exception handling nor garbage collecting. Here is the code below and the output if you are all curious.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace CDataTypes;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    String* str = new String();
    *str = "1 ";
    String* str2 = new String();
    *str2 = "2 ";
    String* str3 = new String();
    *str3 =  "3 ";
    String* str4 = new String("\nEnd!\n");
    cout << str->GetText() << str2->GetText() << str3->GetText() << str4->GetText() << endl;
    const char* s = *str + "H"; // Here is where it goes wrong!
    String* cat = new String();
    cout << "\n" << s << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Code where I think the problem lies:

```
    const char* String::operator+(char obj[])
    {
        std::string str = v->at(this->id);
        str += obj;
        ptr = str.c_str();
        return ptr;
    }
    const char* String::operator+(String obj)
    {
        std::string str = v->at(this->id);
        str += v->at(obj.id);
        ptr = str.c_str();
        return ptr;
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
1 2 3
End!


    ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠∟       ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
Press any key to continue . . .
```

P.S I did some debugging and the variable ptr is not displaying garbage. So my question is how does it return garbage? The variable ptr is global by the way, if that info helps.

Comment: what is `v`? What is `at`? What is `this->id`?

Comment: v is a vector and this->id is the index that is used to retrieve the char* in the vector object v.

Comment: Because I was bored. Sorry if that was misleading.

Comment: So you're building a String class on top of the string class?  Not sure how what you're building is any better than the well-worn c++ template class.

Comment: No only overloaded operator + uses the std::string. Everything else like GetText is not wrapped around the std::string.

Comment: In my timezone, April 1st was yesterday

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `str` is a local variable in your operators - as soon as you return from the operator, `str` is destroyed, and the pointer you return points to deleted memory (the local `str` variable owns the memory that `c_str()` returns a pointer to). If you e.g. return a `std::string` instead of a `const char *` the value in `str` will be copied, and you can then use it in the calling function.

That said, normally `operator+` returns a new object containing the result of an addition - you should likely create a new `String` object and return that.

Comment: str is global by the way. I added that change in the description.

Comment: Agreed.  This is a very beginner mistake to make.

Comment: It's local - `std::string str = v->at(this->id);` creates a new local `str` variable by copying from `v->at(this->id)`

Comment: @Daniel Lopes: You're mixing *pointers* with *pointed to memory* - Doesn't matter that your pointer is a global, the memory it points to is still owned by the local `std::string`

Comment: Thanks I solved it by making a static copy of it and works like I charm. I supsected that was the problem in the first place but I thought making ptr global would have done the job.

Comment: @Daniel Lopez: That's not a solution, that's a kludge to hide a problem - It'll break as soon as you use `operator+` twice in a row before looking at the returned value.

Comment: Okay I fixed it by dynamically allocated it and using the constructor to add the first char*. Is that better or is it still unsafe for multi-threading?

Comment: @Daniel Lopez: You really should make your `operator+` behave as expected. A proper signature would be e.g: `String operator+(String const & L, String const & R)`, and perhaps `String operator+(String const & L, char const * R)` - as free functions, not member functions. We can't say anything about issues in your updated code without seeing it - As a side note, using static the way you did is unsafe also in a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work due to the way you handle/save the string:

You actually never modify the string that's assigned to current instance. The way you do it would work in C# (to some extent) but not in C++.

Let's do it step-by-step:

Assume `this`'s value (i'll just refer to it as `left`) is "Hello", the other string's value (`obj`- I'll call it `right`) is "World".
The expected behaviour of `operator +` would be to append `right` to `left` and return the whole string.

```
std::string str = v->at(this->id);
```

`left` and `right` are unchanged, `str` now has the same value as `left`.

```
str += v->at(obj.id);
```

`left` and `right` are unchanged,`however`str` now contains "HelloWorld".

Now returning the pointer to `str` is in theory the right thing, but as Erik mentioned already, this pointer won't be valid (it could still be valid if you're lucky, but don't assume this!).

Here's how I'd implement it:

```
String& String::operator+(String& other) // pass the other string by value to avoid it being copied!
{
    v->at(this->id) += v->at(other->id); // append the string using std::string's + operator
    return *this; // return this object
}
```